# how to insert newline in a already existing BASH string on the command line

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have typed and executed a long BASH command on the command line. Now I want to split it up. So with the history I have my long command again, but now I cannot give Enter to insert a newline. How  do you do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to do?  An example?

Comment: Which text editor? For `vim` this will be very easy.

Comment: Interactive shell use isn't on topic here in the first place. This should be on [UNIX.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use two shortcuts to do that `ctrl + k` and `ctrl + y`:

```
echo "some command" && echo "some other long command"
```

Now move cursor somewhere (in my example, cursor is marked by `>`):

```
echo "some command" && > echo "some other command"
```

Now press `ctrl + k` - this will cut everything after a cursor:

```
echo "some command" && >
```

Now put `\` (backslash) and press `enter`:

```
echo "some command" && \
>
```

And now paste the part you've previously cut by `ctrl + y`:

```
echo "some command" && \
echo "some other long command"
```

---

**Edit**: to move more easily around in a long command, you can use shortcuts:

- `alt + b` - move one word backwards (on Mac OS X: `ESC + b`)
- `alt + f` - move one word forwards (on Mac OS X: `ESC + f`)

---

**Ultra-solution**

You can also open current line in a editor using `Ctrl-x + Ctrl-e` (two shortcuts, one after another). Then edit it just as a regular text file, save & quit and voila, edited command will execute.

If you want to choose which editor to use, just set `EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: Maybe you could also expand on search features provided by `readline`.

Comment: @devnull - I did it, I've also found out about `ctrl-x` `ctrl-e` and I think my life just changed a bit ;)

Comment: @kamituel I'm not sure if you've *already discovered* `ctrl-r`.

Comment: @devnull - yes, I know `ctrl + r` - but `ctrl + x`-`ctrl + e` is easier, especially for longer commands. So far I found myself sometimes echo'ing command to text file just to edit it - now it's over.

Answer (score 1):

**Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>**.

Interactive Bash uses the readline library for command line editing. Normally readline accepts the line upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (newline, `NL`, `^J`, `\n`, `0x0a`) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (carriage return, `CR`, `^M`, `\r`, `0x0d`). By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> makes readline read the next character literally.

Note <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not a solution. <kbd>Enter</kbd> is transmitted as carriage return, it's equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. In some cases this carriage return gets converted to newline, but not right after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. You need readline to get a newline without accepting the line, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. Readline will split the line exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create text file for script. For example:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello, world!
```

So you will need to execute this:

```
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh
```